# MYSQL / PHP join based on snippet of text in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables. I am trying to find an efficient way to join the tables based on a snippet of text contained in the second table:

```
Table A (documents): 
+-------------+----------------------------+
| document_id | document_text              |
+-------------+----------------------------+
| 1           | My favorite color is blue  |
+-------------+----------------------------+
| 2           | My favorite color is green |
+-------------+----------------------------+
| 3           | Yellow is my favorite      |
+-------------+----------------------------+
| 4           | I like all colors          |
+-------------+----------------------------+
```

```
Table B (snippet): 
+------------+--------------+
| snippet_id | snippet_text |
+------------+--------------+
| 1          | orange       |
+------------+--------------+
| 2          | black        |
+------------+--------------+
| 3          | yellow       |
+------------+--------------+
| 4          | green        |
+------------+--------------+
| 5          | blue         |
+------------+--------------+
```

At the moment the only way I can do it is by having 2 separate loops in my script - the first one on table B and then another one to query table A based on the snippet obtained from table B.

It works, but in my real world data, the snippets are long sentences and table A can contain thousands of rows with a lot of text.

Trying to do it via mysql query takes over 3 minutes to load even when there is not much data.

```
SELECT * FROM table_b left join table_a on document_text LIKE  CONCAT('%', snippet_text, '%')
```

So with the sample data, the desired result would be

```
+-------------+----------------------------+-----------+
| document_id | document_text              | snippet_id |
+-------------+----------------------------+-----------+
| 1           | My favorite color is blue  | 5         |
+-------------+----------------------------+-----------+
| 2           | My favorite color is green | 4         |
+-------------+----------------------------+-----------+
| 3           | Yellow is my favorite      | 3         |
+-------------+----------------------------+-----------+
| 4           | I like all colors          | NULL      |
+-------------+----------------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Hi, yes i have been reading about that but cannot figure out how to join the tables with a full text search. I need to sentence to match exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The quickly way to do that is create iterator in PHP and remove JOIN from second query. If you doing iterator using relationship between tables costs (time) more than using foreach, for, while in PHP.

Try it and don't forked me!

Answer (score 0):

You have a challenge here.  MySQL supports [full text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html), but the caveat is that the search terms need to be constants.

My recommendation is to do an outer loop on `snippets`.  Inside the loop search for the "snippet" in two steps, one using `match` and one using `like` (the former reduces the number of rows for the second).  Then assign the snippet id to those.

So, this repeatedly does:

```
select d.*, @snippetId
from (select d.*
      from documents d
      where match (d.document) against ( . . . ) 
     ) d
where d.document like ('%', @snippet, '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with `locate` function of MySQL, e.g.:

```
SELECT d.id, d.document, s.id
FROM documents d LEFT JOIN snippet s
ON LOCATE(s.snippet_text, d.document) <> 0
ORDER BY d.id;
```

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate)'s the documentation for `locate` function.